# Will car/motorbike fumes affect beer fermentation?

Tags: contamination, off-flavor, extract-brewing

I plan on brewing my beer and letting it ferment for 2 or so weeks in my garage. Unfortunately there are a lot of fumes (eg. From the car and motorbike) and I'm worried that the fumes may affect the fermenting beer. Note that there isn't really any ventilation. But I do have a bubbler air-stopper in place.

Does anybody know if this will affect the quality of the beer, or could it be dangerous to ingest? If so, would you happen to know of any portable ventilation system I could buy to prevent this from being a problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brew and ferment in the garage, and I have no problems with exhaust or any issues with vehicles going in and out. I have done this for the past few years.

the only thing i worry about is the temperature in the garage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the fumes will hurt since the carboy will have co2 pressure but I imagine the temperature variance on a garage floor would fluctuate a lot, which can't be good.